# TypeError: Cannot set property default of [object Object] which has only a getter when running tests

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to run the tests in my project, but I get the error = **TypeError: Cannot set property default of [object Object] which has only a getter**

I use React, Next, Typescript, Jest and React-testing-library, it was running normally, but it happened after I updated dependencies.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@swc/core": "^1.2.127",
    "@swc/jest": "^0.2.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.7",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^3.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.0.11",
    "@types/final-form-focus": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.6",
    "@types/react-input-mask": "2.0.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "<8.0.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.5.2",
    "jest-date-mock": "^1.0.8",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.0"
  },
```

I tried to remove node-modules and yarn-lock and install again, but the error continues.
Any help will be useful. Thank you.